# The trouble with a resizable GameObject

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I am trying to make a resizable GameObject (in my case Quad) by mouse drag. I want to make it work as follows:

1. check whether mouse position is on the GameObject "border"
2. wait for cursor to be outside a "border"
3. simply resize it (so just as in a graphics software)

While I don't have a problem with the first and third step, I have a confusing trouble with the second one.

What my code currently is doing is:

1. check whether mouse position is on the GameObject "border"
2. ...
3. simply resize it

That means I don't have a second step. I thought I can simply solve it with waiting for the second condition to be completed, but it didn't work.

So... how can I make it working as I want?

```
using System;
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Threading;
using UnityEngine;

public class ResizeObject : MonoBehaviour
{
    public GameObject ground;

    void Update()
    {
        Vector3 mousePosition = Camera.main.ScreenToWorldPoint(new Vector3(Input.mousePosition.x, Input.mousePosition.y, Input.mousePosition.z));

        // If I click on the quad in a "border" area
        if (Input.GetMouseButton(0) && mousePosition.x >= ground.transform.localScale.x / 2 - 0.1 && mousePosition.x <= ground.transform.localScale.x / 2)
        {
            // Wait until this condition (cursor is outside a border area) will be true???
            if (mousePosition.x > ground.transform.localScale.x / 2)
            {
                // Reisze a quad
                ground.transform.localScale = new Vector3(ground.transform.localScale.x / 2 + mousePosition.x, 1, 1);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: what are you using for a border? a collider? a Rect?

Comment: Box collider with default properties

Comment: ok so if you sixe your collider properly to your object, and set it to trigger, you will want to start you drag with `onMouseDown(){}` then you will be outside your border when the 'OnTriggerExit()` method fires.

Comment: `Update()` is called every frame .. your two conditions `... && mousePosition.x <= ground.transform.localScale.x / 2` and the second `if (mousePosition.x > ground.transform.localScale.x / 2)` can and will never be true at the same time!

Answer (score 0):

Suppose this is your quad, centered in **c** and with **h** being the half of its height and **w** the half of its width.

```
 -------  -
|       | |  h
|   c   | -
|       |
'-------'
    |---|
      w
```

I don't remember if a quad has a SpriteRenderer property, but if it has, you can use .bounds to get **w** and **h**. Otherwise, you can just attach a BoxCollider2D (as trigger if you don't need it) and use the .bounds to get these values.

Having these values, you can define a value **d**. Lets call the mouse position **m**, you will be touching the border when at least one of these conditions is  satisfied:

- c.x - w - d < m.x < c.x - w + d  and  c.y - h < m.y < c.y + h
- c.x + w - d < m.x < c.x + w + d  and  c.y - h < m.y < c.y + h
- c.y - h - d < m.y < c.y - h + d  and  c.x - w < m.x < c.x + w
- c.y + h - d < m.y < c.y + h + d  and  c.x - w < m.x < c.x + w

You can test **d** as you wish, the bigger it is, the easier it will be to touch the borders.

To do the touch, you can use the built-in methods (that are only usable when you have a collider attached) `OnMouseDown`, `OnMouseDrag` and `OnMouseUp`.

The scaling process is up to you, but it can be done with simple maths using the .bounds values, starting in `OnMouseDown`, scaling at `OnMouseDrag` and ending at `OnMouseUp`.

Comment: Alright, made a fast approach, somehow works, but not as I expected.. what's wrong here? https://pastebin.com/DdiBAR0C

Comment: You are using `||` inside the clauses instead of `&&`. The `||` should be used only between clauses (and this you've done right), but inside them, you should use `&&`.

Comment: E.g. you wrote 

`(boxCollider2D_center.x - boxCollider2D_sizeX - d < mousePosition.x && mousePosition.x < boxCollider2D_center.x - boxCollider2D_sizeX + d) || (boxCollider2D_center.y - boxCollider2D_sizeY < mousePosition.y && mousePosition.y < boxCollider2D_center.y + boxCollider2D_sizeY)`

Comment: But it should be  
`(boxCollider2D_center.x - boxCollider2D_sizeX - d < mousePosition.x && mousePosition.x < boxCollider2D_center.x - boxCollider2D_sizeX + d) && (boxCollider2D_center.y - boxCollider2D_sizeY < mousePosition.y && mousePosition.y < boxCollider2D_center.y + boxCollider2D_sizeY)`

Comment: Fix this mistake for every one of the 4 clauses (and keep them separated with `||` as you already do) and it should work fine.